# Haskell pattern matching on List

Tags: haskell

I know we can use below pattern matching in Haskell:

```
sum :: (Num a) => [a] -> a  
sum [] = 0  
sum (x:xs) = x + sum xs
```

But why can’t we use `[x] ++ xs`?

```
sum :: (Num a) => [a] -> a  
sum [] = 0  
sum ([x] ++ xs) = x + sum xs
```

Answer (score 5):

You can pattern match using constructors and literals but not functions.

Comment: Is `:` a constructor?

Comment: @4castle Yes. [1,2,3,4] is basically just sugar for `1:2:3:4:[]`.

Comment: Indeed, pattern matching using functions would be nonsense in the general case: what would `(\(x++y) -> y++x) "abcde"` evaluate to?